# NSOutlineView: How to Put a Specific Cell Into Edit Mode? (editColumn Method Not Working as Expected)

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I have an `NSOutlineView`. When I edit a cell in it and hit return, I would like the cell directly below it to go immediately into edit mode.

I thought I would use the `controlTextDidEndEditing:` delegate method to find out when editing of a cell had finished, and the `editColumn:row:withEvent:select:` method to put the cell below it into edit mode.

Here's a demo method that I pasted into "appcontroller.m" of the Apple demo code project, "DragNDropOutlineView":

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSTreeNode* treeNodeJustEdited;
    NSInteger indexOfCurrentRow = [outlineView selectedRow];
    if (indexOfCurrentRow < 0) //no row selected
        return;

    treeNodeJustEdited = [outlineView itemAtRow:indexOfCurrentRow];
    NSTreeNode* theRootNode = rootTreeNode;
    NSInteger numberOfChildren = [[theRootNode mutableChildNodes]count];
    NSInteger indexOfLastChild = numberOfChildren - 1;

    if (indexOfCurrentRow < indexOfLastChild)
    {
       [outlineView selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexOfCurrentRow+1] byExtendingSelection:NO];
       [outlineView editColumn:0 row: indexOfCurrentRow+1 withEvent:nil select:NO];
    }
}
```

For some reason, this does the following:

- Correctly highlights the row below the cell
  just edited. But then:
- Disables that
  highlighting, i.e. puts it in light
  grey
- Makes the cell below the cell
  just edited, invisible. Clicking
  twice on that cell returns the table
  to normal.

What am I missing in order to get this method to perform as desired?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another question, it is similar with yours

Hope helpfully.

[NSTableView & NSOutlineView editing on tab key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600793/nstableview-nsoutlineview-editing-on-tab-key)