# How to find an Object (Controller or View) resigned first Responder?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsresponder

I would like to do  some  cleanup activity when a particular object resigns the FirstResponder. Is there any way to detect whether object has resigned first responder status.

What methods I need to implement to know this? Any pointers for this?

I already gone through this link. But I did not get much out of it.

[NSTableView & NSOutlineView editing on tab key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600793/nstableview-nsoutlineview-editing-on-tab-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apples's NSResponder documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSResponder) you should override the `resignFirstResponder` method for you subclass.

Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    [super resignFirstResponder];
    /* Your cleanup code here */
}
```

Comment: Or rather, `return [super resignFirstResponder]`